# Write a bash script to print Narayana cows i.e., 1,1,1,2,3,4,6,9,13,.... without using arrays and by using only three variables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Here is the Link to know about Narayana's cows:
https://oeis.org/A000930

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a bit tricky *using only three variables*.

```sh
a0=1
a1=1
a2=1
echo -n 1,1,1
while (((a0+=a2)>0)) && echo -n ,$a0 && (((a1+=a0)>0)) && echo -n ,$a1 && (((a2+=a1)>0))
do  echo -n ,$a2
done
```